# HVAC heating control with thermostat, on/off or continuous?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I have a [honeywell rth8580wf](https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/69-0000s/69-2717.pdf) heating thermostat.
I wonder what the output of the "white" terminal is (heating control).
Is it only going from 0V to 24V or is it continuous depending on the room temperature?

Comment: Try contacting Honeywell for the data sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a contact closure. When the thermostat wants heat, it closes a contact between the "Rb" and "W" terminals, which allows current to flow.

[Here's a good reference](http://www.electrical-online.com/thermostat-wiring-explained/) for thermostat wiring in general.